# Animation problem

Tags: android, android-xml, android-animation

I'm trying to set up a simple animation that takes an image on the upper right hand side of the screen, moves it to the 30% point, moves in a circle, and them moves back to the edge. See the figure below. However, the current script does strange things, and while it ends up in the right place, almost nothing seems right before that. Also, depending on the Android version and screen size, it might do even more wild things. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

A couple of key points. I want the left edge at the beginning to always be facing the direction of motion. I would like a circular motion where it moves from left to right, but if it can't be done, I'm not set on it, so long as the first part holds true.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <set>
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
            android:fromYDelta="00%p" android:toYDelta="20%p"
            android:duration="001" android:startOffset="0"/>
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-80%p"
            android:fromYDelta="00%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="2000" android:startOffset="1"/>
    </set>
    <set>
        <rotate 
            android:fromDegrees="180"
            android:toDegrees="0" 
            android:pivotY="20%p"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:startOffset="2000"/>
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="70%p"
            android:fromYDelta="00%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="100" 
            android:startOffset="3000"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in a new android project with a button in the main xml layout. It worked. All percentages are of parent size, relative to the view's position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-80%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="2000" />

<rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="-180"
        android:pivotX="-70%p" android:pivotY="10%p" android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="2000" />

<translate  
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="80%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" android:duration="2000"
    android:startOffset="3000" />

</set>
```

Comment: I had thought I had tried this combination, but something about it didn't quite work... Maybe using the linear interpolater caused something. Will award the bounty when I can. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, just checked it out on all of the versions. It works fine on 2.1 and earlier, it does funny things 2.2 and later... Specifically, it goes the wrong direction for the first translate (Although it does end up in the right spot). Still, it's an improvement over what I have, so far.

Comment: What version are you targeting??

Comment: Yes I noticed that on 3.0. The rotate animation's pivotX,Y seem to be interpreted differently in 3.0 than 2.1.  Its different when its taking the U turn. translations are alright though.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe I'll have to do different scripts for 3.0 and 2.1... Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the animation described in your drawing. I split the animation in 2 files
left_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <set>
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-80%p"
            android:fromYDelta="00%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="2000" android:startOffset="0"/>
         <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
            android:fromYDelta="00%p" android:toYDelta="20%p"
            android:duration="2000" android:startOffset="2000"/>         
    </set>
</set>
```

right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromXDelta="-80%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" android:fromYDelta="20%p" 
    android:toYDelta="20%p" android:duration="2000" android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

And this is the code I used in the activity

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_down);
        goBack = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                image.startAnimation(goBack);    
            }
        });
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: I suppose I didn't draw it well enough, but ideally I would like to have the object circle such that it went from facing left to facing right in a gradual motion, then still facing the other direction, moved to the right. In other words, always facing the direction of motion. Will edit my question to explain better.